# Lowest Internal Node - Suffix Trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

Finding the Lowest Internal Node in case of suffix trees is used in many applications. For example, the lowest common internal node of strings in a generalized suffix tree would give the Longest Common Substring.

But I could not think of a way to get the Lowest Internal node in a method better than **O(N*K)** where **N = Number of keys and K= Average length of the Keys**. Is there an easier way to keep track of this node ?

Comment: Can't you remember the lowest leaf and update the lowest internal node while constructing the suffix tree?

Comment: Like keep a global depth value and maintain a global pointer to that node? That should work I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree says that `O(N*K)` is indeed the best you can do with a normal suffix tree.  However it can be preprocessed in a way that makes answering the question much easier.  That leads to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor which has multiple links to external algorithms.

I would suggest starting there.